# OpenGl---connect dots using left and right clicks

Tags: visual-studio, opengl

I have been working on a Assignment for a week now and can't seem to figure it out.

The Point of the assignment is to make dots on a graph connect when you left click. When you right click you make a point but it does not connect to the last point (it's solo, on it's own). When you click on the left button again it should connect to the last point that you made. I got the clicks working but it does not connect well.  The program is below..

```
glBegin(GL_LINES);
for (int i=0 ; i<= numberPoints;i++)
    for(int j =0; j<=numberEdges; j++)
        {
        glVertex2fv(points[edges[i][0]]);
        glVertex2fv(points[edges[i][1]]);
        }
glEnd();
```

// This is the points

```
glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    for( int i = 0 ; i<numberPoints; i++)
    {
       glVertex2fv( points[i]);
     }
     glEnd();


// This is the left click
switch(button)
{

case GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON:
    if(state==GLUT_DOWN)
    {

        points[numberPoints][0] =  plotX;
        points[numberPoints][1] =  plotY;


        previousPointSubscript = numberPoints;
        edges[numberEdges][0] = previousPointSubscript;
        edges[numberEdges][1] = numberPoints;


        numberEdges++;
        numberPoints++;
            glutPostRedisplay();    
                glFlush();
    }
            break;
    case GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON:
        if(state==GLUT_DOWN)
        {
            points[numberPoints][0] = plotX;
            points[numberPoints][1] = plotY;



            numberPoints++;


        } 
    glutPostRedisplay();    
    glFlush();
        break;


}
```

Comment: Looks like part of the code is missing. But one obvious problem is that you're setting the start and end point of each entry in `edges` to the same value (`numberPoints`). `previousPointSubscript` is the same value as `numberPoints` where you make the assignments to the `edges` entries.

Comment: How can I sent you the whole code so you can see that problem. As far as the  previousPointSubscript and  numberPoints being the same isn't that connecting the last point to the new one.

Comment: If the start point and end point of a line are the same, the line degenerates to a point. You may want to step through the whole thing in a debugger, or add some logging, so that you can follow what your code is doing, and see where it does not match your expected logic.

Answer (score 0):

I got it finallyyy!!! Okay what I did was Take the GL_LINE and only had one for loop with variable i.  Then in the left click I flip the edge 0 and edge 1 equals around. So edge 0 is numberPoints and edge 1 is previousPointsSubscript. Then I took the previousPointsSubscript = numberPoints line and put it after the two edges. This gave me lines that connect at every dot.

```
    if(numberPoints>1)
{
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
for (int i=0 ; i<numberEdges;i++)
    {
        glVertex2fv(points[edges[i][0]]);
        glVertex2fv(points[edges[i][1]]);
    }
}
glEnd();


 case GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON:
    if(state==GLUT_DOWN)
    {

        points[numberPoints][0] =  plotX;
        points[numberPoints][1] =  plotY;



        edges[numberEdges][0] = numberPoints;
        edges[numberEdges][1] = previousPointSubscript;
        previousPointSubscript = numberPoints;

        numberEdges++;
        numberPoints++;
            glutPostRedisplay();    
                glFlush();
    }
```

As far as that right button I already had it drawing the dot by its self so all I had to do was add`previousPointSubscript = numberPoints;` under the points and that would connect the lines when the left button was click. If you have questions hit me up.